# Inverse function in integral form

Tags: inverse-function

Here is my question:

Suppose my function is defined in terms of Riemann integral in the following form

$$z=g(y)= \int_{}^{}f(x,y)dx$$.

Is there any explicit formula of inverse function $h(z)$; $y=h(z)=h(g(y))$.

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.
Thank you.

Comment: In general there is no reason for $g$ to be invertible

Comment: Yes, i mean where $g(y)$ is strictly increasing function.

Comment: And even if g was invertible, the inverse may not have a clean, closed form.

Comment: And given that $g$ is expressed as an integral, $g$ itself might not have a clean, closed form.

Comment: Maybe you can provide a concrete example?

Comment: No, not a concrete example. I'm seeking expression containing $f$ and boundaries of the integral.

Comment: Is your integral from $0$ to $\infty$ ? I would consider first the case of $f(x,y)=\sum_{p,q=0}^{p,q=n} a_{pq}x^py^q$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Something like truncated Taylor, or orthogonal polynomials with some wieghts? I want to understand where we are heading to?

Comment: @JeanMarie I also wanted to mention that it was not purely theoretical question, but, unfortunetaly I forgot what I was analyzing.))

Comment: Maybe 1D  vs. 2D cdf (cumulative distribution functions) ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Not exactly. I recalled. This was connected with quantiles of martingale process. I was trying to recover "quantile process" of general martingale process, or at least find some of its properties. I conjectured that for martingales the quantile process should be non-decreasing from some level above 1/2 ($\alpha^{*} > 1/2$) and non-increasing from some level  below ($\beta^{*} < 1/2$). But unfortunately it was of my own interest (I have not much time to deal with something I want for myself). I haven't shown this yet, but i believe it is true. ))

Comment: @JeanMarie I'm sorry to bother you, but I remember there was an inverse formula of Lagrange. Are there any generalizations? Yep. I found the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem

Comment: I had an interesting result concerning reciprocal functions but I am unable at present to find it back... Keep trying...

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you very much. I do appreciate it. Thank you.